# Decision about cultural appropriation by tribal government

Tags: united-states, canada, indigenous-people

Have their been any decisions or recommendations by governments of Native American tribes or nations about the issue of cultural appropriation? I am especially interested in decisions or recommendations that explicitly address the issue of non-natives using costumes marketed as "Native American costumes".

Answer (score 5):

Since so-called "cultural appropriation" generally involves the use of aspects of a minority or disfavored culture in creative works by a non-member of this culture, no tribal government in the US could prohibit or significantly regulate such "appropriation". The provisions of the First Amendment to the Federal Constitution, guaranteeing freedom of speech apply to all such governments, and wold prohibit any such law or  regulation.

Attempts to prevent cultural appropriation must be social and persuasive, not legal and compulsory.

Comment: My interest in the existence of such a decision or recommendation was based on a debate whether one needs to be worried about the idea of cultural appropriation at all. I made the argument that one shouldn't dress up as a Native American as many Native Americans have expressed that they feel that their culture is not respected when people dress up like this. (1/2)

Comment: Someone counter-argued that one can just as easily find claims of Native Americans not worried about the issue as of Native Americans expressing such concerns, and it's not clear whether the opinions I cited aren't just those of a loud minority. A decision or recommendation by a tribal government would show that this is not only a concern of a small minority of Native Americans, but something for which there is a majority consensus (at least within some tribe). (2/2)